# Unable to Send Binary Data (byte[]) using SimpMessagingTemplate

Tags: java, websocket, spring-websocket, stomp, java-websocket

I am able to send string messages to websocket using SimpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend() method, but same is not working when I try to send byte[]. When I send byte[] to the websocket subscription channel, a websocket DISCONNECT event is getting triggered and connection is getting lost. Any Idea to send byte[] to websocket using SimpMessagingTemplate !!!!!

```
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

String body = "Message to be Sent";

template.convertAndSend("/channel", body);   --------- working

template.convertAndSend("/channel", body.getBytes());   --------- Not working
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding a custom message converter to the **byte array**?. Just override **configureMessageConverters** method.

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
        messages.simpTypeMatchers(
                SimpMessageType.DISCONNECT, SimpMessageType.OTHER).permitAll();
        messages.anyMessage().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean configureMessageConverters(List<MessageConverter> messageConverters) {
        messageConverters.add(new ByteArrayMessageConverter());
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried after adding above method. Able to send byte[] to UI and displaying with method like "message.binaryData" . But there is a mismatch of byte[] data. What could be the issue for byte[] mismatch ?